# What is the rule for using a period on a game card?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

For example:

This appears on a card in a game:
"Equipment worn by players on one hand to field baseballs."
The answer appears immediately below it..."Mitt"

Another example:
"Black disk made of hard rubber that is used in ice hockey."

Can I leave the periods as they stand?

Is this a similar case as to use or not to use a period at the end of every bulleted line?

Comment: What makes you think there is a rule about "the end of every bulleted line"? The only rule I know of is that there must be a full stop at the end of a sentence; everything else depends purely on what is clearest.

Comment: TimLymington: Good point. I just clarified the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since these are simply nouns and noun phrases, not complete sentences, there is no clear answer. The examples seem to imply the rule, "Use a period at the end of a clue, but not at the end of the answer."

That's as good a rule as any other, as long as it's applied consistently